# Brightness from Image Difference?

Tags: image-processing, flash-cs5, photoshop

I have two images that are the same, except that one has an adjustment in its brightness.

Is there a way to compute the difference of these images in PhotosShop somehow to see what has changed from one image to another?

image 1

[image]

image 2 (with brightness adjustment)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the blendmode Difference.

Place your first image on top of the second and change the blendmode of the first to 'Difference'.

The darker the pixel the less it changed.